# How to set a Cap value while generating forecasts in Excel 2016?

Tags: excel, excel-2016

[image: excel forecast]

I generated the above forecast chart in Excel 2016.  The lower cap of this data can never go below '0' as you can see from the values (blue).  Is there an option to specify this cap while generating the forecast?  Without this, the lower confidence level forecast provides impractical data.

Here is the options window where I don't see a field to provide cap values explicitly.
[image: options]

Comment: Do you have some supporting data?

Comment: Why not simply round any forecast below zero to zero?  Simply add another column to the output table and say If < 0 then 0 else value. This is statistically set so the other obvious way is to shrink your confidence interval.

Comment: I was wondering if the forecast would come out more accurate if I specify the cap values somewhere.  Shrinking the confidence interval did bring the lower bound graph to '0 or above' but this again means that the forecast is less accurate.

Comment: Hope I am not misunderstanding you.The confidence interval is based statistically on your data as is. Also, the further you forecast ahead.....the more inaccurate generally (there are exceptions) it will be.

Comment: The forecast is statistically computed so the negative forecast is basically a statistic numbers. While it may not make sense in real world, so in order to make a good presentation, u can first populate the forecast, then manually set the negative numbers to zero. Otherwise setting the negative to zero doesn't increase the accuracy of the forecast, i think..